# How to add custom animation property to MUI Theme?

Tags: material-ui

I have the following code. I want to be able to access the centralized animation value in the theme module so I can use it all over the app.

```js
const StyleNetworkIcon = styled(SignalWifiOff)(({ theme }) => ({
  animation: 'beat 3s infinite',
  fontSize: 30,
  '&:hover': {
    opacity: 1,
  },
}));


const useAppTheme = () => {

  const lightTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: 'light',
      // 1. Primary color
      primary: {
        main: mainTextColor,
        contrastText: contrastTextColor,
      },
    breakpoints: breakpointsOverrides,
    components: sharedComponentsOverrides,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const theme = createTheme({
   components: {
      MuiCssBaseline: {
         styleOverrides: `
            @keyframes beat {
               // The animation code (string style)
            }
         `
         // OR
         styleOverrides: {
            '@keyframes beat': {
               // The animation code (CSSObject)
            }
         }
         // OR
         styleOverrides: theme => ({
             '@keyframes beat': {
                 // The animation code (CSSInterpolation)
             }
         })
      }
   }
});
```

> The theme's `styleOverrides` key makes it possible to potentially change every single style injected by Material UI into the DOM. This is useful if you want to apply a fully custom design system to Material UI's components.

Source: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides

Comment: my issue is i dont want to use beat 3s infinite every where i want to inject beat 3s infinite in to theme a custom variable